# Closed form of pairing probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, combinatorics

This situation happened to me at home today, and now it is bugging me. I didn't put all my clothes in the washing machine, and I retrieved 7 sockets, 2 pairs of socks and 3 unpaired ones.

I wanted to come up with the most likely number of pairs but I couldn't. I assume it is close to a binomial distribution but the pairing has made my life miserable.

My random variables are:

- $\Theta$ pairs of socks
- $n$ drawn socks
- $2\cdot k$ paired socks

Is there a way to derive the close- form for $P(y|2\cdot \Theta)$?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/10/tiny-data-and-the-socks-of-karl-broman/

Comment: @
Tim♦ the article is quite interesting. However, I want a closed form solution. Simulating for each $\Theta$ would be easy but I believe there is a closed for as I have one parameter less (no odd socks considered).

Comment: Sure, I didn't say it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ P(2k, n-2k| \Theta) = \frac{2^{n-2k}  \binom{\Theta-k}{n-2k} \binom{\Theta}{k}}{\binom{2\Theta}{n}}.$$

---

**Denominator - Unconstrained no. ways to choose socks**

This is given exactly by the binomial coefficient to choose $n$ objects from $2\Theta$:

$$\binom{2\Theta}{n}.$$

---

**Numerator - No. ways to choose $k$ pairs**

This is again a binomial coefficient: we want to choose $k$ pairs out of a set of $\Theta$:

$$\binom{\Theta}{k}$$

---

**Numerator - No. ways to choose the single socks**

There remain $\Theta - k$ pairs of socks ,and we want to to choose $n-2k$ of these: as before the number of ways to choose the types of socks will be $\binom{\Theta-k}{n-2k}$.

However we now need to account for the fact that for each pair of socks there were two possible choices (eg. left/right foot). So for each type of sock we need to multiply by a factor of $2$, giving:

$$2^{n-2k}  \binom{\Theta-k}{n-2k}$$

---

**Notes**

The above assumes that all of your socks go into the wash in pairs: note that this differs from Baath's assumption in the link that Tim provided, where he supposes that its possible that there are some single socks in the wash.

(**Edited**) As discussed in the comments when $k = 0$ the likelihood will be maximised as $\Theta \rightarrow \infty$. To get around this case you may wish to regularise by making assumptions about the reasonable expectations of the maximum (eg. what's the maximimum no. socks your machine could hold) - this is well suited to a Bayesian analysis where you would place a prior on $\Theta$. Again, Baath's post gives a good introduction.

Here's a [blog post](https://www.infreq.com/posts/2021-07-09-bromans-socks/) I wrote on the explicit calculation for Baath's analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is really elegant. I'm not totally sure about your point on the maximisation of $\Theta$. Intuitevily if $k=0$ the max of $\Theta$ should be obtained at infinity whilst for $2k=n$ the max should be obtained on $\Theta=n$. I would include priors in a real exercise, but to my understanding your close solution is differentiable and can be maximised

Comment: No problem. Good point - I was overly simplistic asserting the maximum would always be  at infinity. I guess what I'm getting at is that it is not guaranteed to be finite. I'll update to clarify this.